# Can't get this trivial haskel program to work

Tags: haskell

I m still learning haskell and i found a tutorial that introduces the IO concepts using the following hangman simple programm

```
import System.IO
import System.Random

main = do
  handle <- openFile "enable1.txt" ReadMode 
  contents <- hGetContents handle           
  gen <- getStdGen                          
  let words = map init (lines contents)     
      (n, _) = randomR(0, (length words) - 1) gen :: (Int, StdGen) 
      word = words !! n                                         
  play word (map (\x -> '_') word) 6        
  build the print the string
  hClose handle                           

play word known guesses
  | word == known = do
      putStrLn known
      putStrLn "You win!!"
  | guesses == 0 = do
      putStrLn known
      putStrLn ("You lose. the word was " ++ word ++ ".")
  | otherwise    = do
      putStrLn known
      putStrLn ("You have " ++ guesses ++ "guesses left.")
      line <- getLine
      let (newKnown, newGuesses) = handle (head line) word known guesses
      play word newKnown newGuesses

    --putStrLn (handle (head line) word)

handle letter word known guesses
  | letter `elem` word = (zipWith (\w k -> if w == letter then w else k) word known, guesses)
  | otherwise          = (known, guesses - 1)
```

enable1.txt is a local file that have lots of words.
I run the file using runhaskill 
and i get the following error:

```
:~/Documents/atom/haskell$ runhaskell hangman.hs 

hangman.hs:22:36: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘6’
    • In the third argument of ‘play’, namely ‘6’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: play word (map (\ x -> '_') word) 6
      In the expression:
        do { handle <- openFile "enable1.txt" ReadMode;
             contents <- hGetContents handle;
             gen <- getStdGen;
             let words = map init (lines contents)
                 (n, _) = ...
                 ....;
             .... }

hangman.hs:30:16: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘0’
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘0’
      In the expression: guesses == 0
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘play’:
        guesses == 0

hangman.hs:37:36: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘handle’
    • In the expression: handle (head line) word known guesses
      In a pattern binding:
        (newKnown, newGuesses) = handle (head line) word known guesses
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn known;
             putStrLn ("You have " ++ guesses ++ "guesses left.");
             line <- getLine;
             let (newKnown, newGuesses) = handle (head line) word known guesses;
             .... }
```

Can anyone please help me understand the issue/ how to fix it.
runhaskell --version is runghc 8.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others already pointed out some issues in your code. Here, I only wanted to provide you a general suggestion.

Most Haskellers, including "experts", always start writing any new top-level function (or binding, in general) from a *type annotation*. That is, by writing `foo :: Type1 -> Type2 -> ... -> ReturnType`. Indeed, this is strongly recommended for several reasons.

First, it helps the programmer focus their mind on what kind of data they have to process or produce. This might be obvious in the programmer's mind for simple programs, but it becomes less trivial in more serious, high-level code.

Second, it prevents the type inference engine to infer unintended types. Consider this code, for instance.

```
foo x = "hello" ++ x   -- line A
```

This is accepted without problems, and `x` is inferred to be of type `String` by GHC.

However, in the programmer's mind `x` should have been an integer, and so, later on, the programmer writes

```
let s = foo 42 in ...  -- line B
```

and GHC complains that `42` is not a `String`. Or even worse, that `Num String` can not be satisfied, meaning that a string in not a numeric type. Now the programmer is puzzled because GHC point to line B as the problem, but that code looks fine to the programmer. "I'm passing an integer, `foo` expects an integer, where is this weird string error coming from?!?"

This is not the compiler's fault -- it has no way of knowing that the code in line A was wrong. However, if the programmer told the compiler, around line A, that `x` was intended to be an integer, then it would indeed have been the compiler fault! The compiler should now complain about the error in line A! And indeed, it does: here's a GHCi quick test.

```
>  foo :: Int -> String ; foo x = "hello" ++ x
error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: "hello" ++ x
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo x = "hello" ++ x
```

Ah-ha! `++` wants a string, but `x` is an integer. So we have to convert it

```
> foo :: Int -> String ; foo x = "hello" ++ show x
```

Now, no error arises.

In general, when coding and making some mistake, GHC might be led to infer unintended types, leading to puzzling errors later on, pointing to seeming perfect code. In such cases, a common technique is to add more and more type annotations, informing the compiler about the programmer's intent, so that GHC can produce more meaningful errors. Eventually, GHC and the programmer agree that something is wrong, and the bug can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting errors because the types are inconsistent in the program.

- `No instance for (Num X)` means that "`X` is not any kind of number".
- `[Char]` is the type of a string (`String` is an alias for it).
- So your error means that something is being used as a string and as a number.

Looking over your code I can see that in `play` you have

- `"You have " ++ guesses ++ "guesses left."` which means that `guesses` must be a string, in order to be concatenated with other strings.
- `guesses == 0` which means that `guesses` must be a number.

If you got this code from the tutorial, then it is a badly written tutorial and you should find a better one. If you wrote it yourself according to the tutorial, then you must have missed a step.

In order to convert a number to a string for printing, you can use the `show` function:

```
"You have " ++ show guesses ++ "guesses left."
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `(++)` a `String` and a numeral type. You should first use function `show` to convert the number to a `String` before you can connect it with another string.

In your code, parameter `word` and `known` is of some type `Num a => a`, but `(++)` accepts only two `String` (i.e. `[Char]`) as a parameter (to be precise, it accept two lists of the same type of elements, and since you have already applied a `String` to it, the other parameter should also be a `String`). So you should replace `word` with `show word`, and the same for `known`.